# UrlEncodedFormEntity equivalent in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json

In java while doing an HTTP post request using `nameValuePairs` we write the following code!

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://sometesturl.com");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("id",1);
json.put("name","john");

try {
  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", "abc"));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("samplejson", json.toString()));

  post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
  }
```

As seen over here we use the `UrlEncodedFormEntity` to encode our request body. Similarly, I need to do the same in Javascript. I have seen the [EncodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) method but that doesn't seem to encode the request body. Instead it encodes the URL.

Can someone tell me how to encode the request body in javascript?

Comment: What about `encodeURI`?

Comment: I haven't tried `encodeURI`. Does it encode the request body only?